# How to make camera LCD show true RAW data in JPG preview and histogram?

Tags: post-processing, raw, exposure, image-review, in-camera-processing

With Canon 650D (and presumably all the other Canon), I noticed that the picture style and full JPG processing is used to generate a review JPEG which is what the camera actually reads when reviewing images through the LCD (and actually, most RAW capable image viewers are using this thumbnail as well).

The problem is, assessing the image through this review JPG and its histogram which has varying degrees of contrast, saturation and exposure tweaks as well as a tone curve and other processing elements I just have no idea about, has resulting in my misjuding of the exposure in the RAW file, leading to over/under exposed images. Clearly these embedded JPG have their benefits; the camera need not reprocess the RAW to show you the review, when the camera gets it roughly right you can be lazy and just extract the JPG and use that.

So, how can I get my camera to show me something in the review image and histogram that is as close as possible to the actual RAW data I will have to work with?

Comment: See also [What is UniWB?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/664/what-is-universal-white-balance-uniwb)

Comment: If you're worried about exposure, is not a histogram view what you want?

Comment: @PatrickHughes yes, but the histogram is the histogram of the embedded JPEG after the camera has applied its rather aggressive (in my opinion) tone curve.

Comment: @user1207217 I totally forgot about that after-processing part, I spend too much time with film.  Thanks for the reminder for the thread!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Magic Lantern to display RAW histogram in live view and image review. Head over to http://www.magiclantern.fm and download the version available for your camera. The installation instructions are different for each camera and can be found in their forums.

In order to view RAW histogram in the preview, you could shoot with the technicolor cinestyle picture style, or any other 'flat' profile.

Magic Lantern also has a ton of other features that will aid you in setting the right exposure, like zebras, warning dots on the histogram and an auto-ETTR mode (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposing_to_the_right). It is slightly complicated, but definitely worth exploring.

Comment: I edited the answer to point out that RAW histogram is also available for image review.

Comment: Even then, the histogram displayed using Magic Lantern has the curves applied for whatever picture style you have selected.

Comment: The "raw" data used for Magic Lantern's RAW histogram feature is from the low resolution video feed, not the full resolution raw data.

Answer (score 13):

You can't view a RAW image, because a RAW file is not an image, it is a set of monochrome luminance values. When the data is converted to RGB using demosaicing certain settings such as contrast, saturation, etc. are applied. There has to be a value for those settings. You are much better off learning to use the histogram (also drawn from the JPEG preview) to judge exposure rather than looking at the brightness of the LCD screen. A perfectly exposed image can look grossly overexposed if the LCD screen is at the brightest setting when you are in a darker environment, and I suspect this has more to do with your exposure problem than which picture style is selected.

The closest you can probably get to what you want is to select the *neutral* picture style. But be aware the images will look flat until you add some contrast, saturation, and work your light curves in post processing.

Here's an image of a scene with a very wide dynamic range when rendered with some highly customized light curves and +1.17 stops brightness adjustment to raise the shadows and then reign the highlights back in a little.
[image: customized curves]
Here is the same RAW file rendered with a fairly standard set of curves: the *neutral* picture style and no brightness adjustment.
[image: neutral curve]
Here is the same RAW file rendered linearly (no curve). The reason the gamma correction line is curved (in the shape of a near perfect curve for y=(√2)^x when x is between -10 and +4) in the histogram is because the exposure stop scale is exponential - there is really twice as much distance between each set of two stops as you move to the right as there was between the previous two stops. If the exposure scale were rendered that way, then the response "curve" you see would be a straight diagonal line.
[image]

I think it is obvious why the camera makers do not allow images to be rendered linearly on the rear LCD screen. But notice that the shape of the histogram is identical in the *neutral* and *linear* conversions. It is the response curve that has changed. Also notice that the very small totally saturated area is not very accurately indicated at the right edge in both the *neutral* and *linear* gamma correction histograms.
Closeup of the *linear* histogram.
[image: histogram]

Here is the final edited image after some additional, fairly aggressive tone mapping has been applied using Canon's *DPP* HDR module to the single RAW file as originally edited with the customized light curves.
[image]

---

Addendum (In response to comments below by user1207217)

Based on the following images, it is fairly certain the histograms rendered in *DPP* from raw files are based on a non-gamma corrected, linearly rendered TIFF preview embeded in each .cr2 file created by a Canon EOS camera.

The small (160x120) JPEG thumbnail preview:
[image: JPEG preview]
There is also a full size JPEG preview image embeded in each .cr2 file that appears to have the exact same processing applied as the thumbnail, other than the obvious resizing.

And the slightly larger (592x395) TIFF preview (rendered as an unedited jpeg):
[image: TIFF preview]
You can view the actual TIFF [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AGRmbcVca8-HTis&cid=35EAC6F70642A2B6&group=0&id=35EAC6F70642A2B6%211127&parId=35EAC6F70642A2B6%211130&o=OneUp).

Comment: I know I can't view a RAW image, which is why I asked "close as possible to the actual RAW data I will have to work with". In addition, I use the histogram, but the histogram is the histogram of the embedded JPEG and not of the RAW data. I tried various picture styles, but all of them are invariably blowing highlights that are not actually blown in the RAW, presumably because of some agressive tone curves in the camera processing.

Comment: @user1207217 "How can I make camera LCD show true RAW image?"

Comment: And the rest of the question body? :)

Comment: And the last paragraph of the answer....

Comment: You still don't seem to understand. The 8-bit per color channel display on the back of your camera is not capable of displaying the 12-14 bit RAW files generated by a modern DSLR. There must be light curves applied and white and black point set before you have a viewable image. If you are that concerned about precise exposure of highlights, then get a light meter and use the zone system.

Comment: I don't meant to be facetious, but do you understand the difference between a tone curve and gamma correction? I am just asking to be able to assess the histogram or image without the tone curve that the camera applies to the JPEG, with (usually standard) gamma correction. This is the best idea one can have of what they have to work with.

Comment: Compare the histograms, particularly the *neutral* and *linear* renderings, in the examples I've added to the answer. They were generated by Canon's *DPP*.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't address the problem of what is happening in image review, which doesn't show these linear histograms (and actually those histograms you showed are very likely log-intensity histograms, not even linear). It's not as if I want the linear histogram, but ideally the gamma corrected RGB histogram, since this is usually the starting point for RAW development (I don't know many? people who use non-standard gamma curves as a matter of routine during RAW development). ...

Comment: ... My problem is with the camera tone curve, which even the neutral style is applying. To get an idea of what I mean, compare the neutral style processed output with the output of dcraw -W RAW_FILE.CR2. Yes there are situations with high dynamic range where blown highlights can't be avoided, but the tone-curve applied by the camera interferes with my decision making process on what level of blown highlights are acceptable compared with the exposure of the remainder of the image.

Comment: There are PLENTY of world class photographers who manage to overcome the limitations you are bemoaning in some very challenging light and get the exposure correct. If the in camera metering isn't accurate enough, or their experience isn't broad enough to understand how what they see on the histogram along with the "blinky" warning translates to headroom in the highlights for a particular scene, they break out the external light meter or bracket away.

Comment: You seem to be unwilling to learn how they do it that way and instead insist on hardware/firmware that is both unnecessary and would increase the cost of a camera such as the 650D significantly. The Canon 1D X has RGB exposure metering which allows it to control the highlights more precisely in each color channel. So if you just have to have the world's most accurate metering system, go spring the 6K for a 1D X! But don;t expect the same performance out of a camera 1/10th the price.

Comment: Histograms are wonderful tools, but like all tools they have their limitations. It is up to the photographer to properly interpret the histogram and apply what it is telling him to the decisions he makes to get the result he wants. That vision is not going to be the same from one photographer to the next. So neither will the *perfect* exposure you seek.

Comment: I don't know what the OP said that you were responding to, but I see nothing wrong in wanting the camera to indicate clipping in the RAW file, so that you can do exposure bracketing or adjust exposure. One can always improve one's skills, but there's nothing wrong with wanting one's equipment to help; otherwise we'd all be shooting manual focus lenses without automatic metering.

Comment: If the equipment had every feature such as this that only a fraction of one percent of users felt they need or even would want, then very few of us could afford the cameras that would result. There are reasons why lower priced cameras have fewer features: they cost less to produce both in terms of research and development and in terms of production expenses. Don't buy a 600D and then complain that it can't do everything a 1D X can do! If you want what the 1D X can do, then pay for a 1D X!

Comment: My apologies for not pointing it out at the time of the original conversation, but it seems you were conflating monitor gamma correction with what is unfortunately referenced as the 'gamma curve' used in converting an image from linear raw data to an image suitable for viewing. The two are different things at different points in the image processing pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is probably using the "Neutral" picture style, this will apply minimum processing with a flat tone curve and no sharpening.

This will give you the closest thing to a raw histogram available in-camera but it will make the jpeg look dull and lifeless - so you'll lose the ability to use the jpeg and preview for anything except judging focus.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't agree - the tone curve is not flat and I am still finding an exposure (and contrast!) difference between a completely neutral RAW file and the Neutral style JPG extracted from said RAW file. With Neutral style changed to minimum contrast (-4) the exposure gets closer but even still there are contrast differences and midtones are pushed considerably (0.5-1 stop). Maybe the picture styles differ between Canon models?

Comment: How are you defining "completely neutral RAW file?" There is no such thing that can be displayed on a 24-bit (8-bit per color channel) monitor! It has to be converted and a light curve applied. If you use a "linear" response (some convertors will let you display one) you will get the nastiest looking dark image you have ever seen, but it is still converted to 8-bits toi be displayed on your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the Neutral style and configuring the camera to use Adobe RGB instead of sRGB would give the closes possible representation for the "original RAW", but it's actually not anywhere near. And depending on the RAW processor you use, it could still be very different (LR process RAWs very differently than the Canon software, and so on).

Anyway, for burn-out zones and so on, the best option would be Adobe RGB color space.