# What does it mean if the main peak of my Histogram is beyond the top of the chart?

Tags: histogram

I tried reading [this thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/450/how-and-why-do-you-use-an-image-histogram)  about histograms, but couldn't understand it well enough to answer this question.

I took some shots yesterday where the main peak of my Histogram was actually off the chart. The histogram had one large peak and most everything else was very low. What exactly does this mean, and if it's something bad (I expect that it is) how can I avoid this in the future?

Here is the Histogram in question :

[image]

and the image can be found [here.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bbischof/4939040919/lightbox/) (Update: I altered the photo, so the link is taking into account Jrista's excellent suggestions. This histogram no longer corresponds to this photo.)

Comment: a warning for arachnophobes: you may not want to look at the original image (;

Comment: @drfrogsplat Lol, I hadn't considered that issue, heh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The height of each individual, vertical line in a histogram indicates how much of that particular tone your image has, or the tones *intensity*. As tones in a histogram progress from left (black and shades) to right (brights and highlights), where a particular vertical line lies indicates how intense the tones represented by that line are.

If one particular tone is extremely intense, and the rest are very low, then the image is primarily comprised of that (or those) particular tones. Generally, this happens in the highlights when they get blown out. It it happens somewhere else, then the histogram is simply telling you that your image is almost entirely composed of that particular range of tones.

It should be noted that the histogram generally does not show enough vertical lines to represent the entire tonal range of an image. Every individual vertical line in a histogram usually represents a small range of tones.

Comment: Good explanation.  I'm thinking it's probably worth pointing out explicitly to the OP that a peak in the histogram can't actually be off the top of the chart.  Off to the right for blown highlights, or off to the left for clipped shadows, sure, but a peak in the middle cannot be "off the chart".  Just further reassurance that it doesn't sound like s/he has lost any data from these particular images.

Comment: Thanks, in the particular image, the big peak was mostly centralized. I am going to edit my question with the pic and the histogram.

Comment: @BBishof: Technically speaking, a histogram stretches infinitely vertically, so as Conor stated, you really can't be "off the chart" from a line height perspective. You can be "blown", which means your highlights cover tones beyond the right edge of the histogram, or "blocked", which means your shades and blacks are shifted beyond the left edge of the histogram. Depending on how many pixels are in an image, any particular part of the histogram may reach a hight beyond what is normally represented, but that doesn't mean anything specifically. In your histogram, you have a high-key image.

Comment: Thanks for the additional help! I guess in this case, it wasn't a problem that my histogram looked as it did.

Comment: Based on your shot, it looks quite under exposed. The fact that the bulk of your tones are bunched up in one fairly narrow spike is also an indication of why your image appears to have such low contrast. I would expect that there be a spike around the highlights area, as about 3/4 of the scene is "white", but I would also expect that other tones would be more exposed.

Comment: Thanks again, hehe. Could you give some recommendations as to fix the issues you present. Just try for higher exposure?

Comment: If you encounter a similar scenario, I would try to find a way to light the scene better. If you have to grab a nearby lamp and rip off the shade to illuminate the scene, I would (I actually do that myself, particularly when trying to photograph insects indoors.) Best to avoid flash with insects (unless you have the right kind or a diffuser.) You could just mess with exposure, however the ultimate end result is most likely to be that you brighten everything, but end up with the same histogram...and same low contrast...only more to the right. Light is your best friend.

Comment: Not to be redundant, but thanks. I did have a small lamp in action, but it was yellow light and thus looked crappy.

Comment: White balance can be adjusted, so the yellow light (probably incandescent) can be corrected. Digital cameras can do some correction...the "auto" white balance setting should take care of a lot of that. If the camera is insufficient at correcting color casts, post-processing software like Lightroom can usually correct it. The two controls, color temperature and tint, generally cover the whole spectrum. Just use the "neutral balance selector" tool, and click on an area that was a neutral white or gray in reality. Lightroom should then automatically remove any orange cast for you.

Comment: @jrista I know these things, I was gnding that with the light it was killing the detail in my shot. Making it lose contrast. I also find that the particular light makes my mages noisy very often.

Comment: Light is light...it simply illuminates, so it shouldn't be making your images more noisy by adding it, even if it is "warmer" than you would like. On the contrary, increasing the illumination of a scene allows you to shift your histogram to the right, which should help you reduce noise. For one, you utilize more of the sensor's dynamic range, particularly highlights, and two, you can often reduce the ISO setting. In general, adding light to a scene should never "kill" detail, only make that detail easier to capture. Now, angle is important, as it allows you to create useful shadows.

Comment: Wow this is great info, I will experiment with this advice soon. I think you should synthesize some of this discussion into your answer, because I think people may find this useful, but might miss the comments.

Answer (score 19):

You might read this histogram like this:
[image: histogram w/ description]

There's nothing wrong with you image. (At most, this histogram says there are "unused" bright tones, so you could maybe expose the photo a bit more, to "move" the histogram a bit to the right -- e.g. use more you your dynamic range to get more of the spider's dark area. But moving to the right might get you overexpose if you add too much light. So it's tricky. And this photo is fine anyway.)

What might give you better idea about tones present is switching the histogram to logarithmic scale. That way you'll be able to see more of the differences between various darker tones.

Comment: Thank you for this detail analysis, of my particular picture.

Answer (score 3):

It simply means there are lots of pixels in your photograph at that brightness level.

Answer (score 1):

If the histogram shows everything bunched up at one end, then have either a very dark or very light image.

**If the histogram is bunched at the right** this means you have a very light image - most of the pixels have recorded lots of light, and lots of pixels will have the maximum value. This is often referred to as *blown highlights*.

While there are some occasions where having a very light image is a deliberate choice for artistic reasons, mostly it means that you have overexposed the image. Unless you are in a fully manual mode, you should check you haven't bumped the Exposure Compensation control off the middle, and if you have an image that is hard to meter accurately you should use the Exposure Compensation control to make a darker image. (Provided you notice when reviewing immediately rather than later). If you are in manual mode you could reduce the shutter speed or use a smaller aperture (higher f-stop number).

And vice versa. **If the histogram is bunched at the left** this means you have a very dark image - most of the pixels have recorded very little light, and lots of pixels will have recorded zero. The fix is the opposite.

Comment: I am sorry my question was unclear before about the location of the fall-out. I have edited the question in an attempt to make it more clear.