# How can I avoid eye pain after indoor portrait shoots?

Tags: indoor, eyes, eye-damage

I have experienced this now for couple times and need to get something done about it. In parties with friends, I shoot friends and family indoors. Light is sometimes sufficient and sometimes not. I take around 200 shots over 3-4 hours maximum. Next day onwards I start having pain in both eyes and especially more in left eye. I realized that pain starts right in party in left eye and that's because I close left eye and keep right open to look through viewfinder. What could I do to avoid this? I don't want to use liveview for some reason.

And by the way, I hold a Canon T2i with 18-55, 55-250 kit and 85/f1.8 prime lens, if that info is helpful.

Comment: Have you seen a doctor?

Comment: My eyes only get sore when I look through the lens at bright lights and if I really pinch my left eye really closed really hard

Comment: @dpollitt Nope...have not seen a doc yet! I have a pair of glasses since I was almost a kid, but eye pain started only lately! What I was specially looking for was if other photographers do something better than I do in terms of technique?

Comment: It's been over a year since this post. I wonder if @vishal.biyani needed a doctor, or did the thing go away by itself, with rest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep both eyes open.

The strain of squinting or closing an eye over time can be very stressful and headaches are common.

http://www.all-things-photography.com/both-eyes-open.html

[How can one learn to shoot with both eyes open, and what are the advantages?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8780/how-can-one-learn-to-shoot-with-both-eyes-open-and-what-are-the-advantages)

Comment: Also, if your camera has it, adjust the eyepiece dipoter control to match your vision.