# Is back-button autofocus possible on the Nikon D7000?

Tags: autofocus, nikon-d7000

A while back I asked about [the purpose of back-button autofocus](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8771/what-is-the-advantage-to-back-button-autofocus) and got several answers.  The Nikon D7000 lacks the "AF ON" button that's present in some higher-end cameras.

Is it possible to use custom settings to configure the D7000 for some sort of back-button autofocus arrangement?  If so, does one lose anything compared with a camera with a true back button dedicated for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this photo.net post: http://photo.net/nikon-camera-forum/00Z4WD

Essentially, the camera is too small to accommodate an AF-ON button.  You can map this function to the AF-L/AE-L button by changing custom setting `f5`.  You will not be able to use the button for autofocus lock or auto-exposure lock if you do so.

Comment: It's not _that_ small of a camera. Seems like they could have managed to fit it in if they worked at the design.

Comment: I suspect it's more about keeping distinction from upper models than about size. If you know enough to ask for back button AF _and_ AE-L, you belong in target market for at least D300.

Comment: @Imre: I share your suspicion, but disagree that that this feature _necessarily_ belongs in a higher price bracket. Pentax has manged to fit both buttons nicely onto the K-5, which roughly compares to the D7000 (although it's actually _smaller_). I mention this not to be all rah-rah Pentax, but because I think it confirms your suspicion — Pentax does this where Nikon "can't" precisely because Pentax doesn't _have_ a more expensive camera to reserve features for.