# Tips for shooting a flood-lit, vibrant carnival procession

Tags: lighting, technique, night, shooting-technique

I'm currently in Rio de Janeiro for carnival where I will be attending carnival at the Sanbodromo. I have a Nikon D3000 with a 55-300 lens. I'll be around 50 to 100 meters away, overlooking the procession.

I'm an amateur photographer, but I would be remiss to waste such a wonderful chance by setting my camera to auto. Can anyone offer me any tips on the type of settings I should be using to produce colourful, vibrant, and bright photos?

The procession is fully flood-lit, and the performers form a cacophony of bright, vibrant colours. On some occasions there will be fast movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of "how to shoot it" will be subjective based on the results you want, but if it were me I would consider the following:

- You'll be shooting at night, but if it's flood-lit you might be able to use relatively short shutter speeds...
- ...on the other hand, you might not want to.  Capturing some motion blur, especially with the vibrant colors, could be a great effect.
- Camera stabilization is recommended.  A tripod would be best, but if that's not possible you should see if you can use something like a [Gorillapod](http://joby.com/gorillapod).
- Pay attention to the highlights in your photo.  With lots of lights and potential long exposures, the opportunity to blow out the highlights to white will be present.  [Use the histogram](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/450/how-and-why-do-you-use-an-image-histogram) to check your exposure.